# Unclosed quotation mark sql?

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting the following error from the following sql statement; can someone please tell me where in my syntax I am going wrong?

Error:

Incorrect syntax near 'Jul'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 's assistant manager in the next

SQL Statement:

```
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[FeedStorage](Date,Title,Description,Link,Category) VALUES (" + date + "," + title + "," + "," + desc + "," + link + "," + cat + ");";
```

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: Is it possible that one of your parameters date, title,desc, link or cat contain single quotation mark?

Comment: I think the problem comes from your `date` property, what's it's format?

Comment: Use parameters. Not concatenated strings.

Comment: This is very good example of sql injection problem. One of your string variable has ' in text. Use parameterized queries instead

Comment: First that your values can be String. Second Date is a registered keyword so shuld be like `[Date]`. Most Important use parameters instead of concatenated strings. (Read about SQL Injection).

Comment: yeah I think the problem is, is that one of the fields (possibly date) has a single quotation mark in it

Comment: No, the problem is that the values are not quoted at all! There are no extra quotation marks around the fields, making SQL think they are column names instead! Other than the obvious SQL-injection of course and not using parametrized queries.

Comment: Ah ok, how should the syntax look then; could you please just show me one of the values with the correct syntax; so that I can repeat for the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further the comments, use parameters rather than just one long string, so instead of what you have currently (trimmed):

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[FeedStorage](Date,Title) VALUES (" + date + "," + title + ");";
```

do something like this:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[FeedStorage](Date, Title) VALUES (@Date, @Title)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This solved it for me thankyou! +1 :)